# How can I retrieve images in a filename based in sqlite through different rawimages in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am confused on how do I retrieved my image(filename based) in sqlite and save it to different rawImages and it is place in different location can anyone help me ?

[From this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjyOB.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a clear example and explanation of what you are trying to do, and what you've tried. Including a code sample.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . Actually I don't know how to code it and it's syntax that's why Im posting here (sorry for bad english)

Comment: you should be able to google ways to pull the images from sqlite, depending on if you just stored the filename, or the whole image..